# Is there an onboard video of the Soyuz MS 10 launch?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight

Does anyone know a link to the video obtained from the Soyuz "outboard" camera showing the  separation of the side boosters of the Soyuz MS10 launch?

Comment: Soyuz MS9 had such cameras: youtube.com/watch?v=fYqPJB7KYP4

Answer (score 6):

A couple of viedeos have been published:

youtube allows to play those at 0.25 speed.